# Laravel 4 dependent/cascading dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

I'm relatively new to programming/Laravel, PHP and jQuery.

I've been trying to get a dependent or cascading dropdown list working for addresses.  I want to select a suburb using a dropdown and then the jQuery will aid in getting the list of streets for a given suburb.

Here is my blade file.
example.blade.php
```

```
<div class="form-group">

{{ Form::open(['route' => 'get_address_path']) }}

<!-- Suburb Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">

{{ Form::label('suburb', 'Suburb:') }}
{{ Form::select('suburb', $suburbs, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

</div>

<!-- Street Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">

{{ Form::label('street_names', 'Street:') }}

</div>
<div class="form-group">

{{ Form::submit('Get Addresses',['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs']) }}

</div>
{{ Form::close() }}

$(document).ready(function(){

var suburb = $('#suburb').val();

$.get( "/getStreets", { suburb: suburb } ).done(function( data ) {
$.each(data, function(i, value){


$('#street_names').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
});
});
});
```

```

Here's my routes.php
```

```
Route::get('/getStreets', function($id) {



return Street::whereSuburb($id);

});
```

```

Here's my model, Street.php
```

```
public static function whereSuburb($id){
return DB::table('streets')

->select('streetName', 'id')
->where('suburbsId', '=', $id)
->get();

}
```

```
If I try print_r(whereSuburb(1)) from my controller, I get the correct streets for the suburb_id of 1.  If i try to do that from my routes.php I don't seem to get anything, I'm not sure how to figure this out, it has stumped me for over a week now.  This is crucial to my app, any ideas, help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

thanks :-)

Regards

Jason

Answer (score 0):

My route works as follows:

```
Route::get('getXYZ', 'ABCController@getXYZ');
```

In Chrome the Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-i) helped me a lot.

Also this post helped me a lot [Cascading/Dependent dropdown list](http://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2014-cascadingdependent-dropdown-list)

HTH